# Xcode build error when building onto device - Library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So my app has run and built successfully on the Xcode simulators. The app is a react native app

However when trying to put it onto a device I get the error.

What steps do I need to take to get this to work?

`Library not found for -lDoubleConversion`
[image]
[image]

Notes:

-I am running the Xcode workspace file
-I did try use_framework! in the Podfile but I don't think that was right and caused more issues

- also tried adding it to the podfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I had this error is that my iOS version required in my podfile was not the same as that as the min version in xcode.

The error generated by xcode wasn't helpful in this case and pretty ambiguous given the range of answers on the internet